# Symfony sensio/framework-extra-bundle is abandoned and i cannot find an IsGranted alternative

Tags: symfony, package, deprecated, access-control

(on a Symfony 5.4 PHP 7.4 project)
So far I am using `IsGranted` to restrict access in controllers per role.
i.e.

```php
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
     */
    public function myAdminPage()
    { // ... }
}
```

Since the `abandoned` warning on `composer update` i.e:
`Package sensio/framework-extra-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use Symfony instead.` I'm trying to find an alternative.

for the case of the `Route` annotation things are straight forward by replacing:
`use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;`
with
`use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;`

But I cannot find an alternative for `IsGranted`.  (for Symfony 5 or Symfony 6)

Any suggestions/advices?
Thanks.

Comment: A package marked as abandoned means that it is no longer being maintained.  Does not mean that you can't still use it nor does it mean that any recommended replacements will have the exact same functionality.  As the answers below indicate, the attribute based replacement requires 6.2 and above.  You can use `$this->isGranted('role')` in place of the current 5.4 annotation.  Or you can just keep using the package and not worry about it.  Transitions like this are always going to a bit messy.

Comment: I usually use @IsGranted on the controller class to prevent access to all actions (functions) in the class.
So it looks like the best solution would be to keep `sensio/framework-extra-bundle`  until I migrate to 6.3...
Thank you both @Cerad and @ThomasL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This :

```
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\IsGranted;
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code

Comment: Trying to use an attribute that was first introduced in 6.2 is probably not going to work very well in 5.4.

Comment: "But I cannot find an alternative for IsGranted. (for Symfony 5 or Symfony 6) "
The question was about symfony 6 also

Comment: `#[IsGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')]` gives the exact same flexibility in `Symfony6.2 / php8.1`. Thanks!. (i did not research this sub case that much but I thought including it would make the post more useful.)

Comment: @pok_net is the answer is right, accept it please :D